# Is there a way to get accurate polynomial regression data?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, regression, polynomials

I am currently creating a sensor that measures the salinity of water in ppm. I've gathered my data and I'm trying to fit a curve that will accurately represent the data to make predictions. The only problem is, no matter how I change the code, the curve is still unrepresentative of the data. Is there any way to fix this?

Here's what I've got so far.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

deg = 4

x =  [26500, 18550, 12600, 8000, 4760, 3800, 3140, 2810, 2580, 2550, 2540]
y =  [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000]

mymodel = numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg))

myline = numpy.linspace(26500, 2540, 40)

plt.title("R Squared = " + str(r2_score(y, mymodel(x))))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(myline, mymodel(myline))
plt.show()
```

And here's the data:

x =  [26500, 18550, 12600, 8000, 4760, 3800, 3140, 2810, 2580, 2550, 2540]
y =  [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000]

*x* is the sensor readout.
*y* is the salinity of the solution in ppm that caused the readout.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There seems to be an inflection around 5k (x=4760), and polynomials aren't good at modeling such things. Did you consider modeling these separately, perhaps as lower degree polynomials?

Comment: I did notice that when I switched the x and y values, 4760 was slightly apart from the rest of the data. I'm still learning regression. How would you suggest to go about this?

Comment: First question to ask here - is it a fluke or something caused e.g. by sensor mechanics? In the first case, do another calibration or simply drop the outlier; modeling it as inverse ratio (y ~= 1/x) will probably help. In the latter case, just fit two simple regressions - quadratic or even linear should work just fine. Worst case scenario, if you aren't sure: store all values and interpolate instead of regressing

Comment: It is highly possible that it could have been a hardware issue. I'll do some recalibration and give try multiple regressions. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're always going to be overfitting your data, i.e. your r2 includes the data you used to fit the model. Also, after plotting your data, it looks like it isn't a polynomial relationship, and you're trying to fit it to a polynomial relationship. Try a log relationship or some other relationship or model your data using some other non parametric technique.